# How to put my text on position:fixed and right inside of my div

Tags: javascript, php, css

I try to put my text on right and inside of the div, but when put `position:fixed` it's going out. I don't know what its the problem I need this text fixed when I make the scroll.

https://codepen.io/ta_io/pen/aMxeXZ

```
<div class="container" style="">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul style="">
        <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ywWBKJ

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/xBNKWP)**.

Use `float` property instead:

```
ul{
   float: right;
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position fixed from your UL class. Float the wrapper right.  Also the position in your UL class does nothing.

```
 .nav-wrapper {
     float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a header element, and gave this element the fixed position, so all the content that is inside this element is fixed.

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 85%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

and removed the fixed position from the logo and menu.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXaOPW

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: dimgray;
}

nav{
  background-color: aqua;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.logo{
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-wrapper{
  margin-left: auto;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

a{
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a veritatis blanditiis nemo id ipsam ipsum officia officiis. Ipsam dicta ad natus corrupti laborum ea tempore unde id est deserunt?




  </div>
```